# Adding an object to array in redux with the index

Tags: react-native

I want to add a new object to an array which is in redux in my react native application. I used splice and it did not work. What is the preferred way to insert items using index in redux?

Comment: Please share us your reducer and actions, if not im pretty sure it will be closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways you can do it.But you should avoid using methods such as push, unshift, splice as these mutate the state which is against the react philosophy.You can [check this link](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.md) for more information on how to update redux store.

You can use

```
function insertItem(array, action) {
    return [
        ...array.slice(0, action.index),
        action.item,
        ...array.slice(action.index)
    ]
}
```

So from the reducer if suppose your(not sure how your reducer is defined) you can call

```
return {...state, array: insertItem(state.array, action)}
```

Considering the item need to be inserted into the `array` property.

If you want to use splice anyway then you need to clone the array using `slice` and then mutate the cloned array like:

```
function insertItem(array, action) {
    let newArray = array.slice(); //Returns new array
    newArray.splice(action.index, 0, action.item);
    return newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new object to an array at a particular index without mutating the array you can use `Object.assign`:

```
Object.assign([], array, {<position_here>: newItem});
```

if you have 2 elements and add an object at `index 3 instead of 2` you will
have `undefined` at `index 2`

Answer (score 0):

splice is supposed to work. Can you show us your code please ?

Do you use it like this ? :

```
var months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];

months.splice(1, 0, 'Feb'); 
// inserts at 1st index position
console.log(months); 
// expected output: Array ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March','April', 'June']

months.splice(4, 1, 'May'); 
// replaces 1 element at 4th index
console.log(months); 
// expected output: Array ['Jan', 'Feb', 'March','April', 'May']
```

Comment: push, unshift and splice are mutative function and should be avoided.